# Combine elements of two lists with if statement in python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to merge two lists depend on the criteria.
I have following codes.

```
R1=[10,20,30,40,50]
R2=[5,10,45,40,45]
for n,m in zip(R1,R2):
    if n>m:
        print(n)
    else:
        print(m)
```

When I run above code,the results is :

```
10
20
45
40
50
```

I don't know how to get that results as a new list like this:

```
results=[10,20,45,40,50]
```

How can I do this? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new `list` and `append()` the result:

```
In []:
R1=[10,20,30,40,50]
R2=[5,10,45,40,45]
results = []
for n, m in zip(R1,R2):
    if n>m:
        results.append(n)
    else:
        results.append(m)
results

Out[]:
[10, 20, 45, 40, 50]
```

You can look at a `list` comprehension to do the same thing:

```
In []:
results = [n if n>m else m for n, m in zip(R1, R2)]
results

Out[]:
[10, 20, 45, 40, 50]
```

Or even more simply:

```
In []:
results = [max(x) for x in zip(R1, R2)]
results

Out[]:
[10, 20, 45, 40, 50]
```

Comment: I am newbie to stack overflow bro. I think I did mistake. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `max` and list comprehension.

```
result = [max(pair) for pair in zip(R1, R2)]
print result
```

Comment: You can improve this a little bit by just doing `[max(i) for i in zip(R1, R2)]`

Comment: Yes, Thanks for the advice. I will improve it.

Answer (score 1):

### Functional solution

The [*map()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#map) and [*max()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#max) functions make short work of this problem:

```
>>> R1 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
>>> R2 = [5, 10, 45, 40, 45]
>>> list(map(max, R1, R2))
[10, 20, 45, 40, 50]
```

### List comprehension solution

Another technique to is to use a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) in a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-list-comprehension):

```
>>> [n if n>m else m for n, m in zip(R1, R2)]
[10, 20, 45, 40, 50]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
R1=[10,20,30,40,50]
R2=[5,10,45,40,45]
temp_list = []
for n,m in zip(R1,R2):
    if n>m:
        temp_list.append(n)
    else:
        temp_list.append(m)

print(temp_list)
```

this should work.
you are trying to print each value, so it is printed on separate lines.

Comment: Welcome, don't forget to mark this question as solved

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` with multiple iterables:

```
>>> R1=[10,20,30,40,50]
>>> R2=[5,10,45,40,45]
>>> it = map(max, R1, R2)
>>> print(list(it))
[10, 20, 45, 40, 50]
```

(Generally, the place to look is in the `itertools` module, but in this case the function is actually builtin).